# How to make line spacing with my current code

Tags: css, html

Hi there I am beginner of coding my question is as below: 
I made some css changes and my spacing is messed up in the html

Orignal html

```
<a
   href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bear">Leanr More</a>
  <p>Here are some bear species:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>Arctos</li>
    <li>Collarus</li>
    <li>Horribilis</li>
    <li>Nelsoni (extinct)</li>
  </ul>
```

original CSS

```
h1,p1,p2 {
  color: CadetBlue ;
}
```

Changed html

```
<a
  href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brown_bear">Leanr More</a>
  **<p1>**Here are some bear species:**</p1>**
  <ul>
    <li>Arctos</li>
    <li>Collarus</li>
    <li>Horribilis</li>
    <li>Nelsoni (extinct)</li>
  </ul>
```

CSS remains

Original Look:

Leanr More
Here are some bear species:

Arctos
Collarus
Horribilis
Nelsoni (extinct)

after change:

**Leanr More Here** are some bear species:
Arctos
Collarus
Horribilis
Nelsoni (extinct)

### below are not codes

I am trying to make one line space between Learn More and here are some bear species, however after I changed `<p></p>` to `<p1></p1>`, it somehow moved up and stuck together.

Can someone please explain why is this and how to solve it?

Comment: `p1` is not a valid tag in HTML. I've flagged to close since this is a simple typographical error and will probably not help future readers.

Comment: Oh i see thank you

Comment: what should i do if i would like to edit different css in every property?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following your question. If I am, though, then you can add a class to your p tag like `<p class="p1">...</p>` and style it as such `.p1 { /*styles*/ }`

Comment: got it hank you

Answer (score 0):

Great question!

First - Your HTML code looks fine with no errors.

Second - Your error lies within your CSS.  The browser doesn't recognize the numbers after the `<p>` tag (p1, p2, p3).  The easy fix is to get rid of them. Please see below on how I would write the CSS:

```
h1, p {
  color: CadetBlue ;
}
```

Using the your HTML and my CSS should produce the result you're looking for.

The way your HTML is written (with the `<p>` tag after the `<a>` tag) will produce a space between Learn More and Here are some bear species.  Your webpage should look something like the following:

Learn More (*Note this will show as a clickable link)

Here are some bear species:  (*Note this `<p>` element will appear CadetBlue color)

- Arctos
- Collarus
- Horribilis
- Nelsoni (extinct)

Hope this helps!